# How to align times by their colon in a LaTeX-tabular?

Tags: latex, time, vertical-alignment, tabular

I have a tabular of the times I in LaTeX.

These times are in the form 4:00 or 12:00 and this have different lengths. I would like to vertically align these times by their colon. Is there a nice way to do this in LaTeX?

Comment: Why not align them to the right?

Comment: @dirk: different digits may have different widths.  The difference between "almost right" and "perfectly right" is very visible in typesetting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `@{}`, or in your case `@{:}` as a column delimiter.

```
\begin{tabular}{l|r@{:}l}
  first & 12 & 00 \\
  second & 4 & 00 \\
\end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 2):

More or less like this:

```
\begin{tabular}{r@{:}l}
12&44\\
2&01\\
22&11
\end{tabular}
```

You may want to introduce some very small space around the ":", like \hspace{1pt}

Answer (score 1):

You can use the package
`\usepackage{dcolumn}`.

Normaly you use it to align floating numbers, but you can use it if you define the delimiter as `:` an the number of digits as `2`

```
\begin{tabular}{D{:}{:}{2}cc}
7:44 & wake-up & home\\
13:01 & meeting & work\\
20:00 & movie & home
\end{tabular}
```